# Access the values of a form from an EventHandler

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, eventhandler

I have a program, where a user fills out a form, then clicks a button that opens a new window on top of the form. That window waits on data from a Port and executes a DataReceived Event Handler.

I want this event to process the data (into a simple string) and then run a method from the main form window, that will compile the form data with the input data and send it further.

However, when executing the method from the Event Handler I cannot access the values of the form - it produces errors, as if all the form elements were completely blank.

It seems the event is running in a new thread, which cannot access the main instance of the form. Is there any way of running the event on the main thread? Or give it the access? I have tried to use global variables, but even they are blank when read from the event... I have been stuck on this for almost two weeks now and I am completely lost...

How can I access the values of form fields inside that event? What is the simplest way of doing this?

EDIT: I want to add more detail on the problem. I have tried following some advice online and tried to use Delegates. This is simplified version of what I have (still not working):

There are two classes: frmMain and frmPortReader.

On start, frmMain opens in a new window. It contains a combobox (cbInput) and button (btnSend). Upon clicking btnSend:

```vb
If frmPortReader.IsHandleCreated Then
        frmPortReader.Close()
    End If

    frmPortReader.Show()
```

The frmPortReader does some things (irrelevant to this problem), but it's main function is to trigger an event when the port receives data.

```vb
AddHandler readerSerial.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   ' Larger code that reads the actual input, processes it, and assigns it to the variable indata
   frmMain.ExecuteEvent(indata)
End Sub
```

Then, in the frmMain class:

```
Delegate Sub MF(inputData As String)
Dim DisplayData As New MF(AddressOf TestDisplay)

Private Sub TestDisplay(indata As String)
   MsgBox("Received data: " & indata & "Currently Selected Index: " & cbInput.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Public Sub ExecuteEvent(inData As String)
   MsgBox("Before Delegate: " & cbInput.selectedIndex)
   Dim paramsArray(1) As Object
   paramsArray(0) = inData
   BeginInvoke(DisplayData, paramsArray)
End Sub
```

When executing, the ExecuteEvent method displays two MessageBoxes with the data it reads from the form (selected index of ComboBox). The first one, being read directly without a Delegate, produces -1, while the one inside Delegate produces error: "cannot call invoke or begininvoke on a control until the window handle is created"

Comment: If with `forms` you mean Windows Forms, retag your question with `winforms`. -- Since the handler notifies when data has been received, it shouldn't process anything, otherwise it can block and new data sent in the meanwhile may be lost. You should enqueue a new Task for processing. The procedure that initializes the listener should receive or trap the UI Thread SynchronizationContext, then post back to it using a delegate method (see `SendOrPostCallback`). An `IProgress<T>` delegate can be used to simplify this procedure.

Comment: See the [IProgress<T> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) and the [Progress<T> class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) that implements it.

Comment: I would also check you're using the correct instance of your main form.  The way I read your question sounds a little like you might be referencing the Class object rather than the actual form your calling these methods from

Answer (score 0):

I think Hursey nailed it. You're using the default instance of frmMain when that is not the form that is being displayed on your screen.

Change:

```
frmPortReader.Show()
```

To:

```
frmPortReader.Show(Me)
```

Now, in `frmPortReader`, you can get a reference to the instance of `frmMain` using the `Owner` property:

```
Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   ' Larger code that reads the actual input, processes it, and assigns it to the variable indata
    Dim main As frmMain = DirectCast(Me.Owner, frmMain)       
    main.ExecuteEvent(indata)
End Sub
```